# What is correct way to do message formatting and validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

**Situation**

I have Action in my controller that accepts JObject in parameters.

`public IActionResult Test(JObject request)`

For development environment requests will be sent as simple json with data using "application/json" content type.
But for production environment we will use JWE to protect our data. So request will be JWE token and content type will be "application/jose".

I create my custom `InputFormatter` so I can easily read this token, decrypt it and retrieve my `JObject` to pass it to controllers action. Everything till this moment was ok but I faced problem of sending error message if something wrong with token (e.g. couldn't decrypt because pass phrase is wrong or the token itself is corrupted). `InputFormatterResult.Failure()` doesn't accept any parameters.

So I want to understand where should I do this.

HttpRequest -> ***something*** -> Action of controller

Comment: Maybe you can use the `fluentvalidation`. 
This page will describe you how to use it.
https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#using-the-validator-in-a-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that `InputFormatterContext` contains ModelState that I can populate with errors and it will go through all pipeline.